# mongoose find with populate after where clause not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I m not able to populate and find the specify category post in mongoose. It alway return me all post, it does not filter the post with specifying the category name, in **searchQuery.category** I m passing the searched category.

```
   var query = posts.find();
if (searchQuery.tags) {
    searchQuery instanceof Array ?
        query.where('tags').in(searchQuery.tags) :
        query.where('tags').equals(searchQuery.tags);
}
if (searchQuery.publish) {
    query.where('publish').equals(true);
}
if (searchQuery.category) {
    query.populate({
        path: 'category',
        match: { name: searchQuery.category },
        model :'Category'
    });
}
if (searchQuery.series) {
    query.populate({
        path: 'series',
        match: { name: searchQuery.series }
    });
}
return countPost(searchQuery).then(function (count) {
    return query.select('title heading tags description blogImage createAt')
        .skip(((parseInt(pageNo, 10) || 1) - 1) * parseInt(limit, 10))
        .limit(parseInt(limit, 10) || 10)
        .exec()
        .then(function (posts) {
            return { post: posts, total: count, currentPage: pageNo, limit: limit };
        });
});
```

Here my code, it does not evaluate the category.

this code give me filtered record

```
query.populate({
        path: 'category',
        match: { name: searchQuery.category },
        model :'Category'
    }).exec(function(err, post){ console.log(post)}); // this query return only searchedQuery object.
```

Answer (score 1):

The .populate method works a bit differently.
It does not filter the original collection. Instead it applies the query you pass to the collection that is populated. If the query applies it populates. Else - sets null instead of populated document.
So disregarding this `match: { name: searchQuery.series }` you will still receive all the posts.

There are 2 ways of solving this.

1. Get all the posts and filter out where category is null (not populated)
2. Use aggregation with $lookup operator and populate at DB level

Comment: thank for reply, .populate({..}).exec() return the filter result but if i am not use exec with populate then it will return all post , why ?

Comment: @AnkitRana could you please show how exactly are you calling it with and without exec()? And what results you are getting.

Comment: @ Antonio i define the code in question you can see this

Comment: @AnkitRana let us try to simplify this. You assume that .exec changes populate behavior and you receive different number of records, right? Please try to debug it. Can you confirm that theses 2 queries indeed return different  number of records? http://jsbin.com/doreqewite/1/edit?js Create a different script.js and try running them. The thing is that I tried to run populate with .exec and without it and there is no difference for me. So I'd rather assume that the problem you're having is connected with .skip and .limit you are applying or with something else.